# How to show feedback/error messages in a backbone application

Tags: model-view-controller, validation, backbone.js, crud

I'm working on a simple CRUD proof of concept with Rails/Backbone/JST templating. I've been able to find a lot of examples up to this point. But after much searching and reading, I've yet to find a good example of how to handle these scenarios:

- info message: new item successfully added to list (shown on list screen)
- info message: item successfully deleted from list
- error message: problem with field(s) entry
- field level error message: problem with entry

The Backbone objects are:
Collection (of "post" Models) -> Model ("post" object) -> List/Edit/New Views (and a JST template for each of these views)

So, I'm looking for a high level description of how I should organize my code and templates to achieve the level of messaging desired. I already have a handle on how to perform my validation routine on the form inputs whenever they change. But not sure what do with the error messages now that I have them.

Here is the approach I'm considering. Not sure if it's a good one:

- Create a "Message" Model, which maps to a "View", which is a sub-view (if that's possible) on my existing views. This view/model can display page level messages and errors in the first three scenarios I mention above. Not sure if it's feasible to have a "sub-view" and how to handle the templating for that. But if it's possible, the parent templates could include the "message" sub-template. The message view could show/hide the sub-template based on the state of the message model. Feasible? Stupid?
- For the fourth scenario, the model validation will return an error object with specific messages per each erroneous field each time a "model.set" is called by form field changes. I don't want to interrupt the "model.set" but I do want to display the error message(s) next to each field. I want to know how to factor my edit/new template and Post model/view in such a way that I don't violate the MVC pattern. I.e. I don't want to put references to DOM elements in the wrong plage.

Sorry if this is vague. If you're inclined to help, let me know what code snippets could be helpful (or other details) and I'll provide them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You create a global eventbus. When ever an error appears trigger an event. Your view that should show the message listen to the events on this eventbus. Doing so, your error message view dont needs to know all of your collection and vice versa. The eventbus is simple:

```
var eventBus = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
```

Add it to your collection and trigger it when ever `add` was called:

```
var myCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
     initialize: function([],eventbus){
          this.bind('add', function(obj){eventbus.trigger('added', obj)}
      }
})
```

Take also a look at the article: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/07/19/references-routing-and-the-event-aggregator-coordinating-views-in-backbone-js/